# .NET Core 1.1.0 and Angular 2 app: Can't find variable:WeakMap on Safari

Tags: angular, typescript, polyfills

I've deployed a .NET Core 1.1.0 + Angular 2 + Typescript app on ASPHostPortal.
Everything works fine from Chrome and Firefox but when I try to open the site from Safari I get the following exception on the console:

> Can't find variable:WeakMap

and the site doesn't start, stucking on "loading" screen.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

[Sakuto solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43538615/1058278) solves weapmap issue but now the safari console showns these errors:

[image]

Someone knows what is the problem?
Obviously on Chrome and Firefox the site keep working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WeakMap is not implemented in Safari as stated in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

You can, however, use a [polyfill](https://github.com/Benvie/WeakMap) to handle this. The other solution would be to use Angular CLI which will handle everything for you, from the bundling to the deploying.

Comment: This seems to resove the weakmap issue but now the safari console logs other errors: I've updated my question.

Comment: You are supposed to create one new "thread" for your question. But in this case, it's just caused by an unproper CSS I think. Safari is maybe more sensible than others browser